# Updating angular version from 10 to 12 shows : An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: angular

While updating the angular from 10 to 12, I was following all the steps which are already written here

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=10.0-12.0

However after doing all these steps properly, here are the errors I am getting:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module: 

/home/../angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/../angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/index.js from /home/../angular/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/common.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/../angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/package.json.
```

I could not understand how to fix it. I tried to remove `"type": "module"` from `/home/../angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/package.json` but it did not solve my problem.

I will so glad if someone helps me solve this issue

Comment: Did you try to delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock and npm i again? It might solve your issue

Comment: I tried this way after your comment. but nothing changes. having the same error :( @mikegross

Comment: Is it possible for you to go from 10 to 11 and then 11 to 12? Hopefully you won't face an issue going from 10 to 11 and then 11 to 12. It is not recommended jumping 2+ major versions when upgrading.

Comment: Can you share teh content of your package.json in the question?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while upgrading my application's angular version to 13 from 12. I missed updating the package `ng-packagr` to its latest. After updating the `ng-packagr` to the latest version error disappeared.

Version I used: `"ng-packagr": "~13.3.1"`

Answer (score 3):

Solved problem by

```
ng update -- to update angular for the local project
```

open package.json to change all the angular items in "dependencies" and "devDependencies" from 12 to 13
ex:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
}
```

```
npm install
```

All done

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your workspace is tidy and try the below command. This could resolve your problem.

```sh
# Step 1: Update your cli
npm i -g @angular/cli

# Step 2: Migrate your workspace cli
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 10 --to 12

# Step 3: Migrate Angular Core
ng update @angular/core --migrate-only --from 10 --to 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically ionic referred angular update to the angular framework site. But following the steps was not working for me. What I have done is

1. run
   `sudo npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest` 
   to install latest ionic package and run 
   `npm outdated`
   to get outdated packages.
2. run
   `npm install package_name@latest --force` (replace 'package_name' with the outdated package name) for every package shown in outdated package list
3. Ignore any warning during update.
   **TIP:*Updating all the outdated packages saves you from app's low performance and improves security***